# Function paramater that is either a string or a number or a function that returns either a string or a number

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, higher-order-components, typescript-types

I'm building a React app using TypeScript.

I'm trying to define a function (for a HOC) that takes in a parameter called `value`, which can either be a string, or a number, or a function that returns a string or a number.

So what I tried is:

```
const myHOC = (
  value: string | number | () => string | () => number
) => WrappedComponent => // ...
```

But TSLint complains about everything that comes after the second `|` (so basically about both functions).

It says:

```
[ts] Type expected. [1110]
```

for the `()`,

```
[ts] ',' expected. [1005]
```

for the `=>` and

```
[ts] 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. [2693]
[tslint] Forbidden bitwise operation [no-bitwise]
```

for the `string` / `number` respectively.

How can I tell TypeScript what `value` is?

Comment: *"TSLint complains"* - what exactly does it say?

Comment: @kinduser Edited the question.

Comment: I guess it can't parse it properly. Try `string | number | (() => string) | (() => number); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSLint (as well as TypeScript) can't parse it properly, you could wrap your function types into braces, to let it understand what you aim for.

```
const myHOC = (
  value: string | number | (() => string) | (() => number)
) => WrappedComponent;
```

**Edit**: If you wish these two function types to accept an optional parameter, which are the `WrappedComponent` props, you'll have to import the interface that stands for the props of that component (if only they are not in scope) and use it inside them with a question mark `?`, to let TS know that it's optional.

```
import { WrappedComponentProps } from './WrappedComponent';

const myHOC = (
  value: string | 
         number | 
         ((props?: WrappedComponentProps ) => string) |
         ((props?: WrappedComponentProps ) => number)
) => WrappedComponent;
```

Comment: Thank you this works! Just as a follow up question: How can I tell typescript that this should be okay for any function with any parameters (as long as the return is correct)? Because TypeScript now complains when `value` is a function that takes in a parameter, but I need this to be possible.

Comment: @J.Hesters You want both of them to accept an optional parameter?

Comment: You can also create type aliases to make this more readable:

`type StringOrNumber = string | number;

type FnStringOrNumber = () => StringOrNumber;

const myHOC = (
    value: StringOrNumber | FnStringOrNumber
) => WrappedComponent => ...;`

Comment: @kinduser To be specific I would love if I could somehow tell typescript that the input parameter for these functions are the props for the `WrappedComponent`, because at some point in the HOC there is this line: `const badgeValue = typeof value === "function" ? value(this.props) : value;`.

Comment: @J.Hesters I've updated my answer, let me know if it does the trick for you.

Comment: @kinduser Thank you for updating your answer. Unfortunately no, it does not. Because this way I would have to know which component is wrapped and could only wrap one component. But I would like the HOC to work with any component. I know TypeScript as something like `<T>` but I haven't yet understood it.